# How to find when a table was last accessed/updated for SQL Server 2000 sp4

Tags: android-activity, sql-server-2000

I need to find if a certain table has had any activity (update/query). Is there are way to find this information in SQL Server 2000 (sp4 to be specific)

There is a helpful query using sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats, but it is supported only post SQL Server 2005. I am looking for something similar on SQL Server 2000.